# Need to get miniconda basebath from mac using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

Hi I am trying to get miniconda base path, to set the  PATH but fail to get it, tried with shell and command , output getting as same input : "conda info | grep -i 'conda av data dir'|awk '{print $6}'"

```
-name: get_conda_path
shell: echo $(conda info | grep -i 'conda av data dir'|awk '{print $6}')
register: conda_path
- set_fact:
path: "{{conda_path.stdout}}"
```

Attached output image for the refrence[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5zDX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That's simply because of `echo` used as part of `shell` module.

When you remove `echo`, ansible executes `conda info` command & then applies the `grep` followed by `awk`..

```
- name: get_conda_path
  shell: "conda info | grep -i 'conda av data dir'|awk '{print $6}'"
  register: conda_path

- set_fact:
  path: "{{conda_path.stdout}}"
```

Comment: for this command not working

shell: "conda create -n wme_sst_env python=3.9.7 -y"

Comment: It's not related to above question, post another question

Comment: add new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71818978/need-to-create-environment-for-python-by-conda-in-ansible

Comment: Using grep piped with awk is redundant in most cases,  like this one. You can use awk like `awk '/something to search/{print $6}'`

Comment: TBH, I’m not a fan of `shell` & that too for fetching/parsing something from output. It’s better to use `pattern` with `regex_search`. The command was working without `echo` & I just posted that as an answer..

Comment: it is nnot working

Comment: @santhosh, what's not working? Can you be more specific? An error log would be of some use rather saying `not working`

Comment: - name: get_conda_path
  shell: "conda info | grep -i 'conda av data dir'|awk '{print $6}'"
  register: conda_path

- set_fact:
  path: "{{conda_path.stdout}}"

and error getting as commad not found

Comment: that means you haven't got any `conda` installed. If installed, it's not on the PATH which OS expects.

Comment: My task is install miniconda and set path, 
Installation is success , to set env  path only i  using above command to get conda  path

Comment: works => command : /bin/bash -l -c "conda info | grep -i 'conda av data dir'|awk '{print $6}'"